# How to retrieve non-matching results in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

I'm sure this is straight-forward, but how do I write a query in mysql that joins two tables and then returns only those records from the first table that don't match. I want it to be something like:

`Select tid from table1 inner join table2 on table2.tid = table1.tid where table1.tid != table2.tid;`

but this doesn't seem to make alot of sense!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find rows in one table that have no corresponding row in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415438/how-to-find-rows-in-one-table-that-have-no-corresponding-row-in-another-table)

Answer (score 22):

You can use a [`left outer join`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to accomplish this:

```
select
    t1.tid
from
    table1 t1
    left outer join table2 t2 on
        t1.tid = t2.tid
where
    t2.tid is null
```

What this does is it takes your first table (`table1`), joins it with your second table (`table2`), and fills in `null` for the `table2` columns in any row in `table1` that doesn't match a row in `table2`. Then, it filters that out by selecting only the `table1` rows where no match could be found.

Alternatively, you can also use [`not exists`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
select
    t1.tid
from
    table1 t1
where
    not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.tid = t1.tid)
```

This performs a `left semi join`, and will essentially do the same thing that the `left outer join` does. Depending on your indexes, one may be faster than the other, but both are viable options.  MySQL has some good documentation on [optimizing the joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html), so you should check that out..

Comment: The `left outer join` where `is null` is exactly what I needed... +1 for the help!!