# How do you return data Joined with a Blacklist table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please review this statement:

```
   SELECT TableID FROM Table t1
   INNER JOIN BlackList b ON b.TableID <> t1.TableID
```

I was thinking this statement returned everything from `Table` that wasn't found in the `Blacklist` table, but instead it returned nothing at all (0 rows).  If I'm trying to return everything from `Table` that IS NOT found in the `Blacklist` table, what's the best way to do this?   I assume you can do this:

```
  SELECT TableID FROM (
    SELECT TableID, CASE WHEN b.TableID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END OnBlackList 
    FROM Table t1
      LEFT JOIN Blacklist b ON b.TableID = t1.TableID
    ) tb1
  WHERE tb1.OnBlackList = 0
```

But I was looking for a shorter, more efficient solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the difference between `Table.ID` and `Table.TableID`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, sorry,fixed it.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One basic way is using a `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT TableID FROM Table t1
where NOT EXISTS (select * from BlackList b where b.TableID = t1.TableID);
```

This will select rows in `t1` that are not present in the `BlackList` table.

Comment: There are some complicated joins where I could see that `EXCEPT` might be faster/efficient.  But just like `UNION`'s and other similar functions, I recommend using them only when absolutely necessary.  (I assume `EXCEPT` will actually calculate the full join, rather than just using the matching primary key.)  Especially if you're dealing with primary keys the basic `NOT EXISTS` construction is highly likely to be faster.  (And it's not db-specific.)

Comment: I think it's difficult to make such a sweeping statement. YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TableID FROM dbo.Table
EXCEPT
SELECT TableID FROM dbo.Blacklist;
```

Comment: TY for your answer, Does Except run only on the columns in both selects?  They must be the same amount and types of columns i assume?

Comment: @AaronBertrand:  You were quite right in your comment to my answer, on both counts (hence also why I wasn't familiar with `EXCEPT`).  Deleted mine and upvoted yours.

Comment: `EXCEPT` is a great command, but when doing this on two blacklist tables, using `NOT EXISTS` works much faster.

Comment: OK, so use `NOT EXISTS`. <shrug> If you know enough to test performance between different methods, why aren't you looking up syntax alternatives on your own?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TableT1.TableId FROM TableT1  
LEFT OUTER JOIN BlackList ON  
TableT1.TableID = BlackList.TableID  
where BlackList.TableId IS NULL
```

I wrote the above, but now I also found a previous question/ answer in StackOverflow:
[How to find rows in one table that have no corresponding row in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415438/how-to-find-rows-in-one-table-that-have-no-corresponding-row-in-another-table)

Comment: When publishing code it's good practice to use the code format tool, as with the other responses here.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
SELECT TableId FROM Table
WHERE TableId NOT IN (SELECT TableID FROM BlackList)
```

This will work regardless of the columns you add in the main select statement.

Comment: Be very careful with `NOT IN`. This can return incorrect (or at least unexpected) results if `TableID` can be `NULL`. While unlikely in this specific case, future readers might not realize that `TableID` is probably the PK (and therefore not nullable).