# Selecting messages with no responses in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL query:

```
select * 
from message
where not exists (select message.* 
                  from message
                  left join message_reply on message.id_message = message_reply.id_message)
```

I am working in Oracle SQL Developer.

What I want is to get every message in my database which has no answer connected to it.

System works like this: message is a received message and message_reply is our answer to this message. So there is 1:n connection 1 being message and n being the reply.

My query returns an empty table.

Yes there are plenty of messages with no answers in our system to be shown.

As per usual I have tried a lot of tutorials online such as:

https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-not-exists/

[How to find rows in one table that have no corresponding row in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415438/how-to-find-rows-in-one-table-that-have-no-corresponding-row-in-another-table)

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql_certificate/get_data_from_multiple_tables.htm

But neither did the trick for me.

Thank you for any helpful information.

Comment: Your subquery selects all messages with all replies. So `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is never true. Only if there were no rows in the mesage table at all would the subquery not find anything and `WHERE NOT EXISTS` would be true, but then there would be nothing to select :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exists logic is off.  You intended to use this version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM message m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM message_reply mr
    WHERE m.id_message = mr.id_message
);
```

In plain English, the above finds all messages for which there does not exist any matching message reply.  You were mixing up the left anti-join with exists.  The anti-join version would be:

```sql
SELECT m.*
FROM message m
LEFT JOIN message_reply mr
    ON m.id_message = mr.id_message
WHERE mr.id_message IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for a quick reply, but neither works and both return an empty table.

Comment: ...then perhaps your message table has no records not having any reply.

Comment: @Matěj Němec: The queries are both correct. If no rows are returned, then there is no message without a reply in your database. So there were two errors involved here: your flawed query and your wrong assumption concerning the data. You can mark this answer as accepted, because it answers both these issues.

Comment: I shall examine the database tomorrow, but it is possible. Thank you. Once my assumptions are confirmed, I will mark it as answered.

Comment: You were right I was wrong, thank you.