# Retrieve non matching record using join

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, table A and table B.

Both have 4 matching records and table A contains 6 records that do not match.

With the help of join how do I retrieve non matching records?

Comment: You want to return 10 rows (4 common + 6 from A) or only the 6 non-matching from A?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `left outer join` and test for `B.ID is null`. This sample will run in SQL Server 2008 but the query works in versions before that.

```
declare @TableA table (ID int)
declare @TableB table (ID int)

insert into @TableA values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
insert into @TableB values (1),(2),(3),(4)

select A.*
from @TableA as A
  left outer join @TableB as B
    on A.ID = B.ID
where B.ID is null
```

Result:

```
ID
--
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this posts once

[How to retrieve non-matching results in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080358/how-to-retrieve-non-matching-results-in-mysql)

[Returning non-matching records between 2 tables sql server](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=113377)