# inner join, right join ? Count rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can I discover which orders has no details rows ?

> Table Orders: orderId (int), customerName, deliveryDate (date), price (decimal)
>
> Table Details: detailId (int), orderId (int), sku (varchar), quantity (int)

I tried (with no success) :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Details.detailId) AS Tot,
    Orders.orderId
FROM Details
INNER JOIN Orders
    ON Details.orderId = Orders.orderId
GROUP BY Details.orderId
HAVING Tot = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a LEFT OUTER JOIN [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). See also [How to retrieve non-matching results in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080358/how-to-retrieve-non-matching-results-in-mysql) .

**INNER JOINS** select the rows from two tables that match. Everything else will be discarded and is not available in the result set that you can query with `HAVING`

**LEFT OUTER JOINS** select a row for every entry in the left table (Orders). Always generate a row for the right table (Details). If no matching row can be found the values will be NULL. We can use this to our advantage, try:

```
SELECT Orders.orderId, Details.orderId
FROM Orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN Details              -- generate a row for every row in a
                                     -- make null if not matching
ON Details.orderId = Orders.orderId  -- match condition
WHERE Details.orderId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

How about `not in` or `not exists`?

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1
                  from details d
                  where d.orderId = o.orderId
                 );
```

If you don't want all columns, then `select` the ones you want in the outer `select`.

Answer (score 0):

select it with a outer join an check if orderId is null... like this

```
SELECT
    o.*
FROM orders o
LEFT OUTER JOIN details d
    ON d.orderId = o.orderId
WHERE d.orderId IS NULL
```