# Left-join gives incorrect result

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 2 tabels A and B. These 2 tables have 1 coloumn in common : A.A1 and B.B1. Table A has 800 rows and table B has 500 rows. Clearly, some rows in table A dont have any matching rows in table B.
Now, i want to see "what rows in A that do not match row in B" by issuing this query :

```
select * from A 
LEFT JOIN B on A.A1 = B.B1 
where date(b.trt_date) = '2017-11-18' and a.tcs_type = 'SALES' 
order by a.tcs_no asc
```

This query gives out result the same as INNER JOIN. 
**Why ?**

When I put this query into a VIEW, it gives out the expected result

This should be dead simple. I am just confused.

I am using : mysql, navicat, sqlyog

Comment: You are referencing table B in the where clause! date(b.trt_date) = xxx will remove all rows where there are no matching rows in B. You probably meant to include that predicate in the join clause.

Comment: ok .. yes, finally i found the answer. thanks...you are right

Comment: Incidentally, date() cannot use an index. If you can write that as `b.trt_date BETWEEN  '2017-11-18 00:00:00' AND '2017-11-18 23:59:59'`, then it can use an index.

Comment: Find out what left join does. Find out how to express it clearly & concisely. Putting things in quotes does not clarify. Clarifying clarifies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [left join turns into inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256304/left-join-turns-into-inner-join)

Answer (score 2):

Your query:

```
select * from A 
LEFT JOIN B on A.A1 = B.B1 
where date(b.trt_date) = '2017-11-18' and a.tcs_type = 'SALES' 
order by a.tcs_no asc
```

Works simillary as an `INNER JOIN` because you put this `WHERE` condition:

```
date(b.trt_date) = '2017-11-18'
```

You cut, in this way, all rows where `b.trt_date` is `null`.

How the condition encapsuled in an `ON` clause of `LEFT JOIN` works:

- If the condition is not satified for main table -> Doens't show the row
- If the condition is OK for main table but not for the secondary table -> Show the row with all fields of secondary table as `NULL`
- If it's OK for both main and the secondary table -> show the row with all information

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from A 
LEFT JOIN B on A.A1 = B.B1 
WHERE B.A1 IS NULL
```

Similar post here [How to retrieve non-matching results in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080358/how-to-retrieve-non-matching-results-in-mysql)